# Count number of emails in outlook folder

Tags: outlook

I want to count the number of mails i received which has word say 'xyz' in subject line.But I do not want it to count duplicates, I mean if I get a mail with subject 'xyz' and I reply to it including myself I want that to be counted as 1 not 2. Is it possible in outlook?

Comment: Which version of Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's possible definetly, you did not specify the techno you would use but a sample code using interop could be:

```
var outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
var mapi = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
var root = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultfolders.olFolderInbox)

var folders = root.Folders;
int count = 0;
for(int i = folders.Count; i >= 1; i--)
{

  var folder = folders[i];
  count += GetCount(folder, 0);

  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);

}
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folders);

//... function
private int GetCount(MAPIFolder folder, int count)
{

  var folderItems = folder.Items;
  if(folderItems != null && folderItems.Count >= 1)
     {
         for(int i = folderItems.Count; i >= 1; i--)
         {
          //Check item.Subject for string logic
           count++;
          //Add item in collection variable to check duplicates, 
          //generate an id with subject + creationtime for tracking?
         }
     }
  if(folder.Folders != null && folder.Folders >= 1)
    {
        var subFolders = folder.Folders;
        for(int i = subfolders.Count; i >= 1; i--)
          {
             var subFolder = subFolders[i]
             count += GetCount(subFolder, count);
             Marshal.ReleaseComObject(subfolder);
          }
    }
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
   return count;
 }
```

Hope it helps someone,